# Friend unable to use an app I created for him, is there a way to provide the java files needed to run my app with the exe?

Tags: java, swing, jar, jframe, executable

Friend cannot open an exe I made from a jar file. Gives a java exception, assuming that simply means he doesn't have the correct version of java, is there a way for me to include the files needed to run it with the exe, to remove the need of having java downloaded?

I made a java program with jframe for a friend to help him do some calculations and I was able to convert it into an exe but when he downloaded it and tried to run it, it gave a java exception, is there a way I can include the java files needed to run the app with the exe?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create a .jar file and then convert it into an .exe file. You can refer to this link https://medium.com/@sulabh4/how-to-make-a-executable-file-from-your-java-code-3f521938ae5c